# Wait response from websocket on client side

Tags: websocket, dart

I have a form, and I would send data by Websocket.

I would like receive a response, before to continued.

```dart
@CustomTag('register-user-sign')
class RegisterUserModule extends PolymerElement {
    @observable String email = "";
    @observable String pass = "";

    RegisterUserModule.created() : super.created();

    void    send() {
        WebSocket   ws;
        var         index;

        index = new Store('demo', 'infos');
        index.open()
        .then((_) => ws = index.getByKey('wsocket'))
        .whenComplete((_) {
            if (ws != null && ws.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
                ws.send({'email': email, 'pass': pass});
                // wait here the response ?
            }

        });

    }
}
```

It's possible ? Or there is on other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an other solution with the Completer class.

Voilà :

```dart
Completer  _completer;

Future<String>  send(Map data) {
    _ws.send(JSON.encode(data));
    _completer = new Completer();
    return  _completer.future;
}

void    _get_data() {
    _ws.onMessage.listen((MessageEvent data) {
        _completer.complete(data.data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket.send is non blocking, you should use the onMessage method and handle the Stream to receive your response

```dart
ws.send({'email': email, 'pass': pass});
ws.onMessage.listen((e) {
  handleMessage(e.data);
});
```